# Mac Multi-touch in a web application

Tags: javascript, macos, web-applications, titanium, appcelerator

In a web application (or even in Titanium Desktop) is it possible to recognize and use multi-touch gestures (i.e pinching/3-finger swipe)?

Comment: I would keep an eye out for Appcelerator updates to follow the WWDC keynote soon.

Comment: Oh, yah - apple released more info about lion w/multitouch. I was actually looking for this before then, but didn't get around to asking the question till now. Good timing, I suppose. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about browser support . Browsers which support HTML5 extensively , give u javascript events for gestures , take  a look at this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/mobile/touch.html) .

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to be supported on desktop, or at least not in a version of Webkit that I have

Comment: Hmm, it didn't seem to work in firefox either, but I stumbled across a related article in the comments - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events
Looks like firefox has some support for touch events, looks useful. Too bad it doesn't work in WebKit.

Comment: Also see MagicTouch.js (depends on an NPAPI plugin though): https://github.com/borismus/MagicTouch